# Celery with django and rabbit as broker is skipping every alternate task

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery

I am using celery to do the background work for my django application with rabbitmq as broker. But I am getting strange issue in production. Whatever task I initiate, every alternate task is getting skipped, there is no trace for that. Same setup is working fine in my dev environment.

Only reason I can think of is that there might be another consumer who is consuming message, but I am unable to figure it out. I am using the default rabbit config file and have create a separate user and virtual host.

I can't find even find anything related to this, any help will be highly appreciated.

This is the output of rabbitmqctl status command

```
Status of node 'rabbit@ip-172-31-21-247' ...
[{pid,22526},
 {running_applications,
 [{rabbitmq_management,"RabbitMQ Management Console","3.2.4"},
  {rabbitmq_web_dispatch,"RabbitMQ Web Dispatcher","3.2.4"},
  {webmachine,"webmachine","1.10.3-rmq3.2.4-gite9359c7"},
  {mochiweb,"MochiMedia Web Server","2.7.0-rmq3.2.4-git680dba8"},
  {rabbitmq_management_agent,"RabbitMQ Management Agent","3.2.4"},
  {rabbit,"RabbitMQ","3.2.4"},
  {os_mon,"CPO  CXC 138 46","2.2.14"},
  {inets,"INETS  CXC 138 49","5.9.7"},
  {mnesia,"MNESIA  CXC 138 12","4.11"},
  {amqp_client,"RabbitMQ AMQP Client","3.2.4"},
  {xmerl,"XML parser","1.3.5"},
  {sasl,"SASL  CXC 138 11","2.3.4"},
  {stdlib,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","1.19.4"},
  {kernel,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","2.16.4"}]},
 {os,{unix,linux}},
 {erlang_version,
 "Erlang R16B03 (erts-5.10.4) [source] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [async-threads:30]        [kernel-poll:true]\n"},
 {memory,
 [{total,79683424},
  {connection_procs,1040632},
  {queue_procs,316520},
  {plugins,-381968},
  {other_proc,14279336},
  {mnesia,78184},
  {mgmt_db,1332496},
  {msg_index,41792},
  {other_ets,1129440},
  {binary,36806032},
  {code,20026884},
  {atom,703377},
  {other_system,4310699}]},
 {vm_memory_high_watermark,0.4},
 {vm_memory_limit,1578945740},
 {disk_free_limit,50000000},
 {disk_free,3877945344},
 {file_descriptors,
 [{total_limit,924},
  {total_used,18},
  {sockets_limit,829},
  {sockets_used,15}]},
 {processes,[{limit,1048576},{used,341}]},
 {run_queue,0},
 {uptime,47427}]
...done.
```

Thanks
Anurag

Comment: check to see if you have a rogue worker process running somewhere that is consuming jobs.  I'd suggest stopping all celery jobs (using `systemctl`, `supervisorctl` or whatever), use `pgrep celery` on all machines to check if any workers are left over.

Comment: hello @scytale , I was using supervisor. I stopped all the processes and then manually killed all the rogue celery workers (3 of them were there). Now all tasks seems to be executing. But now the question is that how do I ensure that this never happen. I always use supervisor to manage processes. I believe this issue would have come if supervisor itself was killed and its child processes remained (please correct me if I am wrong). is there a way to ensure that this never happens?

Comment: in theory the master process should clean things up cleanly. sometimes it doesn't. you can use the `killasagroup` option in supervisor to kill all worker processes immediately, preempting the master process. I've posted my suggestion as an answer. please accept.

Comment: ok thanks for your help. I have enabled the killasgroup option. Will continue to monitor if this issue happens again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check to see if you have a rogue worker process running somewhere that is consuming jobs. I'd suggest stopping all celery jobs (using systemctl, supervisorctl or whatever), use pgrep celery on all machines to check if any workers are left over.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced with a similar issue and the reason was same with scytale mentioned. But it wasn't an extra rogue worker process, it was another celery process connected to same rabbitmq uri. In that case you should route the tasks to right worker. If you don't define any routing rules all tasks will go after the default route and since workers don't discover other worker's tasks you will get key errors and tasks will drop.

Below are the documentation for Celery routing;

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html